# Minimising the largest eigenvalue of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-matrices

I have the following $5 \times 5$ matrix $A(x)$

$$A(x) = x  \begin{bmatrix} 17 &   24  &   1   &  8  &  15 \\ 23 &     5  &    7   &  14   &  16  \\ 4    &  6   &  13   &  20  &   22 \\ 10  &   12   &  19   &  21  &    3 \\  11 &    18  &   25  &    2    &  9 \end{bmatrix}  + (1-x) \begin{bmatrix}  1  &    1 &     1  &    1    &  1 \\   1  &   2    & 3   &  4     & 5 \\ 1   &  3 &    6    &10  &  15 \\ 1   &   4  &   10   &  20  &   35 \\ 1    &  5   &  15   &  35   &  70 \end{bmatrix}$$

When I calculated the matrix $A$,

$$A(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 16x + 1 & 23x + 1&         1&   7x + 1&  14x + 1 \\  22x + 1& 3x + 2&   4x + 3&  10x + 4&  11x + 5 \\  3x + 1&  3x + 3&   7x + 6& 10x + 10&  7x + 15 \\ 9x + 1&  8x + 4&  9x + 10&    x + 20& 35 - 32x \\ 10x + 1& 13x + 5& 10x + 15& 35 - 33x& 70 - 61x \end{bmatrix}  $$

I would like to find the value of $x \in [0,1]$ that minimises the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A(x)$.

I don't understand what means the "minimising the largest eigenvalue of a matrix".

Please help me to solve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Largest eigenvalue in absolute value, I assume.

Comment: How can I find it? Please help me to do it @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: How can I help you if I don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: I do not understand what you said? I guess I write my question in a clearest way. I have the matrix A(x) that is given. I want to find the value of x that minimizes the largest eigenvalue of the given matrix A(x).  How can I find x? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: What if the eigenvalues are complex?

Comment: Thank you so much for your attempt, But in fact, I do this question in matlab. So, In fact, I need to how to find it in order to write its matlab code. @Moo

Comment: The first one is the result of that. @Moo

Comment: sorry since  $x \in [0,1]$, the third one is the result @Moo

Comment: But, I really cannot understand how to Find the five eigenvalues as a function of 
x and then to find the min of each of those over your range. Show your solution way. please. @Moo

Comment: Okay, you have solved correctly, I guess, but since you don't show how to find these values, I don't understand by looking at only outcomes. dear @Moo

Comment: I don't see such topic in my academic life. I just try to learn matlab coding. Therefore, I need to learn its solution way. @Moo

Comment: Is this a Matlab question or not? If you are asking here, it is presumed you are asking for help with the mathematics behind the question.

Comment: Yes this is Matlab question. But in order to write Matlab code, I need to know how to solve in mathematically way. I ask for it in order to learn its math solution @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You don't really need to if you just want to write code; Matlab has builtin features precisely for dealing with matrix problems like these.

Comment: I don’t know how to deal with it in Matlab.  @SimplyBeautifulArt please inform me :)

Comment: But we don’t want to use toolbox. For that, I asked it @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You can find algorithms for computing eigenvalues [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms).

Comment: This is really not understandable for me. Okay I know how to find eigenvalues basically but I cannot set up this question thanks for help. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: You have had 6 hours to refine your answer. I see nothing. Why?

Comment: Because question is this. I can post the photo of the question in the textbook if you want. But this is matlab programming question. I just want to learn behind its math. So nothing is to re-write this question. What all I know is this dear @RodrigodeAzevedo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the OP. Do you realize that you have an unpleasant attitude towards people who want to help you? For some time, on this website, young (or not) people of a modest level appear very arrogant. The coronavirus may not work for them, but in this case, they may think about getting treatment.

Let $U(x)=xA+(1-x)B$. Since $U(x)$ is a positive matrix (the $u_{i,j}$ are $>0$), $\rho(U)=\max_{\lambda\in spectrum(U)}|\lambda|$ is an eigenvalue of $U$; moreover it's a single eigenvalue and it's the sole eigenvalue, the modulus of which, is $\rho(U)$.

We consider the characteristic polynomial of $U(x)$: $p(x,y)=$

[image]

Note that $p(x,\rho(U(x)))=0$. Now we seek $x_0$ s.t. $y_0=\rho(U(x_0))$ reaches $\min_{x\in[0,1]}\rho(U(x))$. Since $\rho(U)$ is always a single eigenvalue, we deduce that $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=0$ where

[image]

Finally $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the intersection of the implicit curves $p(x,y)=0,\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x,y)=0$.

By drawing the graphs of the functions, we see that the intersection point with maximum $y$ is obtained for $x\approx 0.8$.

Using a zoom, we obtain this approximation: $x_0\approx 0.796035,y_0\approx 63.378642$.

With a software, we can do better

[image]

EDIT. Anwer to the OP. Method 1. You calculate the minimum for $x\in [0,1]$ of the function $\rho(U(x))$; unfortunately, there is no explicit formula for $\rho(U(x))$ because it's a root of a polynomial of degree $5$.

Method 2. You solve the system $p(x,y)=0,\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x,y)=0$ by choosing the initial point well. Example with Maple

fsolve({$p(x,y),\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}(x,y)$},{$x=0.8,y=63$});

There must be a similar procedure in Matlab.

Comment: which my word is unpleasant? I don't really do this. Sorry for this if my answers seems unpleasant. I don't have such a bad intent. I just say that I have no information except for this. Therefore, I could not give answer to their questions. This is matlab programming question. and I have no idea about this math topic. I only ask to learn behind its math. I am only matlab learner.

Comment: And many many thanks for your great answer!! :)

Comment: again sorry and really I don't want to seem a rude user. I just try to learn my question and I have really no idea. And I tried to express that I don't understand what they said.

Comment: OK, I understand now.

Comment: well, I understand,but I have one more question. How can I do it in matlab? By defining det(U(x)-yl) as a function in matlab, can I find this values by the use of fminsearch? Do you have an idea? please share it with me if yes. thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you so much for your additional information :)